# Correlation test for binary DV and categorical IV

Tags: r, logistic-regression, correlation, categorical-data, binary-data

I have two variables and I want to test the correlation between them. The dependent variable is binary (0/1) and the independent variable is categorical with 5 possible categories. My instinct was to do this using logistic regression, but I am wondering if there are more suitable alternatives given some of the challenges below.

Basically, I am having a little bit of trouble properly interpreting the logistic regression output in light of my specific goal. In R, the default parameters for estimating logistic regression dictate that it holds one of these categories constant (as the intercept) and reports the coefficients of the other categories *relative* to the intercept. That's not what I want; rather, I want to be able to report the effect of each category in the IV on the DV with all other categories held constant. I have tried suppressing the intercept, but have read elsewhere that this is generally not a good idea in logistic regression. So I am wondering if anybody can shed light on this strategy, or offer alternatives that will help me get to where I need to be. Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to test a correlation and your categorical var is ordinal. You can use spearman correlation.
If both variables are truly categorical you can try to use http://sites.utexas.edu/sos/guided/inferential/categorical/chi2/
https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab
There are a bunch of other metrics as well. 
If you want to use logistic regression one hot encoding will help. If you want to go fancy try catboost.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to accomplish. Whether you suppress the intercept or not, your categorical and numeric variables are all controlled for.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand -Yes, my question relates more to how to properly interpret the coefficients here. The output for a logistic regression with intercept reports results for all variables *relative* to the intercept (more or less likely than the reference variable to correlate with the DV, if at all). I'm unsure of the proper way to report that if I *really* want to say how each individual IV category correlates with the DV. Is there a way to do this without suppressing the intercept? Or is suppressing it appropriate? Alternatively, is there a different test that would better accomplish this?

Comment: I have provided a lengthy answer that is hopefully helpful. The book I cited is an excellent resource if you want to learn more from a practical perspective (and not something that is formulaically dense).

Answer (score 0):

##### Explanation

I think you are misunderstanding how the intercept works with categorical variables, so it is important to remember that it is a linear equation (why this is important is detailed below). The intercept in this case is the reference level of your category. So if you have a predictor that has three categories (e.g. "Control Group", "Treatment 1", and "Treatment 2"), whichever is either the default or assigned first level will be used in the intercept (in this case, "Control Group" would be used because it is the first level.

##### Single Predictor Case

An example below from the `hdp` data I borrowed from [here](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/mixed-effects-logistic-regression/), which is supposed to be used for a logistic GLMM, but can still be used here for a simple demonstration of a regular logistic regression:

```
#### Load Data ####
hdp <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hdp.csv")
hdp <- within(hdp, {
  Married <- factor(Married, levels = 0:1, labels = c("no", "yes"))
  DID <- factor(DID)
  HID <- factor(HID)
  CancerStage <- factor(CancerStage)
})
```

We will fit the data with remission as the binary outcome (whether or not cancer goes into remission is coded as 0/1) and sex as a categorical (with female as the reference group). We will also add a continuous variable of red blood cell count (RBC). Then we summarize the model:

```
#### Fit First Model ####
fit <- glm(remission 
           ~ Sex
           + RBC,
           family = binomial,
           data = hdp)
summary(fit)
```

If you run the last code `summary(fit)`, you will get a lot of info, so I have only included the coefficients below:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept) -1.26965    0.41124  -3.087  0.00202 **
Sexmale      0.05474    0.04835   1.132  0.25753   
RBC          0.07602    0.08210   0.926  0.35447
```

##### Linear Equations and Predict Function

This linear equation is represented as:

**remission = -1.26965 + (0.05474 * gender is male) + (0.07602 * RBC)**

So if we have a female, the equation drops the middle term (because female is dummy coded as 0, so .05 * 0 = 0.) and simplifies to:

**remission = -1.26965 + (0.07602 * RBC)**

You can actually test this in R with the `predict` function. Here, I have created new data that has a new male and a new RBC count of 5.

```
new.data <- data.frame(Sex = "male",
                       RBC = 5)
```

Then obtain a prediction from your model with this data's linear equation:

```
predict(fit.add, 
        newdata = new.data)
```

The output is below:

```
         1 
-0.8347961
```

This is correct, as the linear equation when the gender is male (gender = 1) and the RBC is five would equal:

**remission = -1.26965 + (0.05474 * 1) + (0.07602 * 5) = -0.8347961**

If they are female, this equation would become:

**remission = -1.26965 + (0.05474 * 0) + (0.07602 * 5) = -0.88955**

##### Resource

By the way, a good book on learning logistic regression in R is *Practical Guide to Logistic Regression* by Joseph Hilbe, and a specific section detailing how to interpret categorical predictors can be found on Page 28.

Answer (score 0):

For testing correlations among categorical variables, apply chi-square and check its Pearson's residuals. You can then plot them using the corrplot package.